# In flatpickr in onChange event value is not assigned with alpinejs

Tags: javascript, flatpickr, alpine.js

I try to add flatpickr to my livewire 1.3 / alpinejs 2 app and on onChange event I failed to apply
selected value to var defined in alpine Component, as :

```
/* Init alpine Component */
        <div class="hostel_item_commands_row p-3" x-data="hostelViewPageComponent()"  @custom-event="console.log($event.detail.foo)">

new_hostel_enquery_start_date::<div x-html="new_hostel_enquery_start_date"></div>

...
<input
    type='text'
    id="flatpickr_new_hostel_enquery_start_date"
    class="form-control editable_field"
/>

...

<script>
        function hostelViewPageComponent() {

// In onChange of flatpickr this would ref to flatpickr, so I assign self var
            var self = this;
            var fp = flatpickr(document.querySelector('#flatpickr_new_hostel_enquery_start_date'), {
                dateFormat: 'Y-m-d', // 2018-01-21 12:39:36
                altFormat: "F j, Y",
                altInput: true,
                inline: false,
                locale: "en",
                onChange: function(selectedDates, date_str, instance) {
                    console.log('selectedDates::')
                    console.log(selectedDates) //valid
                    console.log('date_str: ', date_str);

                    console.log('self::')
                    console.log(self)  // I check content of self var : https://prnt.sc/u64eug


                    // self.$dispatch('custom-event', { foo: 'bar' , date_str: 'date_str' })
                    // If to uncomment line above I got error : ypeError: self.$dispatch is not a function

                    self.new_hostel_enquery_start_date= date_str
                    console.log('self.new_hostel_enquery_start_date::')
                    console.log(self.new_hostel_enquery_start_date)
                    // looks like value is NOT assigned to my component new_hostel_enquery_start_date var

                }
            });
            // alert( 'AFTER flatpickr::' )
            return {
                new_hostel_enquery_start_date:'-',
                ...
```

Why self var does not work here?
Which is valid way ?

Thanks!

Comment: you should move the flapickr init into an `init()` function and call it using `x-init="init()"`

the function doesn't the Alpine.js "this" context set so it's probably defaulting to the window, an init function called by x-init shouldn't have that problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `hostelViewPageComponent` function isn't executed with the Alpine.js "this" context set so it's probably defaulting to the window.

You should move the flapickr initialisation into an `init()` function and call it using `x-init="init()"`. A function called by reference by `x-init` should have the correct `this` context.

See the following:

```html
<div class="hostel_item_commands_row p-3" x-init="init()" x-data="hostelViewPageComponent()"
  @custom-event="console.log($event.detail.foo)">

  <input type='text' id="flatpickr_new_hostel_enquery_start_date" class="form-control editable_field" />


<script>
  function hostelViewPageComponent() {
    return {
      new_hostel_enquery_start_date: '-',
      init: function() {
        // In onChange of flatpickr this would ref to flatpickr, so I assign self var
        var self = this;
        var fp = flatpickr(document.querySelector('#flatpickr_new_hostel_enquery_start_date'), {
          dateFormat: 'Y-m-d', // 2018-01-21 12:39:36
          altFormat: "F j, Y",
          altInput: true,
          inline: false,
          locale: "en",
          onChange: function (selectedDates, date_str, instance) {
            console.log('selectedDates::')
            console.log(selectedDates) //valid
            console.log('date_str: ', date_str);

            console.log('self::')
            console.log(self)  // I check content of self var : https://prnt.sc/u64eug


            // self.$dispatch('custom-event', { foo: 'bar' , date_str: 'date_str' })
            // If to uncomment line above I got error : ypeError: self.$dispatch is not a function

            self.new_hostel_enquery_start_date = date_str
            console.log('self.new_hostel_enquery_start_date::')
            console.log(self.new_hostel_enquery_start_date)
            // looks like value is NOT assigned to my component new_hostel_enquery_start_date var

          }
        });
      }
    }
  }
</script>
```